# ¿Cómo crear una columna booleana personalizada en la consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un base de datos y quiero la proporcion de creación de cuentas por mes dividido si han rellenado su fecha de nacimiento o no, cada mes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATE,
  `birthdate_filled` BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `birthdate_filled`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2019-04-27', true),
  ('2', '1', '2019-04-27', false),
  ('1', '2', '2019-04-27', true),
  ('1', '3', '2019-04-27', false);
```

Entonces intenté:

```
SELECT user_id, created_at, birthdate_filled, created_at  FROM users,
(SELECT 1 IF users.birthdate_filled ELSE 0 FROM users) AS birthdate_filled
GROUP BY created_at
```

Pero no funciona, pienso que necesito hacer un custom column.

En efecto, me devuelve:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF users.birthdate_filled ELSE 0 FROM users) AS birthdate_filled WHERE users.cre' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece entender que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) ejercicio,
  MONTH(created_at) mes,
  ROUND(SUM(birthdate_filled)/COUNT(*)*100) 
  porcentaje_fecha_nacimiento_cumplimentada
  FROM users
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Para obtener:

```
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| ejercicio | mes  | porcentaje_fecha_nacimiento_cumplimentada |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|      2019 |    4 |                                        50 |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Por favor, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Y cómo crearía la columna booleana si no la tuviera y dependiera de `created_at` (true si hay fecha, false en caso contrario)

Comment: Suponiendo que, si no hay fecha, habría un `NULL`... podrías hacer un `COUNT(created_at)/COUNT(*)` y así podrías calcular la proporción que necesitas sin crear ese campo booleano. Si tuviera otro valor, podrías usar la función `IF()`